# Using a pre-defined function in a jQuery .each call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the .each() function on multiple jQuery objects like this:

```
$('#table_1').each(function(){ /* foo */ });
$('#table_2').each(function(){ /* foo */ });
$('#table_3').each(function(){ /* foo */ });
```

I have not found a better way of doing this than writing out each function individually.

Defining a function like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    foo: function() {

        //Some code
    }
});

$('#table_1').each(foo);
```

returns a "cannot read property 'call' on undefined function" error in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just define foo as a regular function and it will work.

Comment: `var foo = function() {}; $("#table_1, #table_2, #table3").each(foo);`

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is not visible outside this wrapper and you can only invoke it with `jquery` object.

Rather than wrapping inside

```
$.fn.extend({
```

simply make it

```
var foo = function() {
    //Some code
}
```

or

```
function foo () {    
    //Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with `$.fn.extend` you are extending the jQuery object but you just need to create a simple function

```
var foo = function(position, obj) {
  console.log('iterated object:', obj);
}

$('#table_1').each(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call foo function directly on each element:

```
$('#table_1, #table_2, #table3').each(function() {
   $(this).foo();
});
```

I would suggest that you could place a common class on those elements and select by this class:

```
$('.commonClass').each(function() {
   $(this).foo();
});
```

---

Or you could do the iteration inside the `foo` function:

```
$.fn.extend({
  foo: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      // Do your stuff here
    });
  }
});
```

and initialize like this:

```
$('.commonClass').foo();
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

`foo()` turns text color in to red for each selected element

```js
$.fn.extend({
  foo: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.style = 'color:red';
    });
  }
});

// Call the function without each()
$('li').foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal "native" function. Keep in mind that jQuery inverts the order of arguments, so you have ths index first and then the element (also in the context `this`).

```
function doSomething(i, el){
    $(el).html('I was changed ' + i);
}
$(div).each(doSomething);
```

**jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdc2a011/**